# Swift invert UIRotationGestureRecognizer for subviews

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I want to invert the rotation from a UIRotationGestureRecognizer for specific subviews. My rotation occurs in 90 degree phases (so CGFloat.pi / 2 )

```
func localhandleRotateGesture (localrotateGesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if localrotateGesture.state == .ended {
        if localrotateGesture.rotation > 0.0005{
            localrotateGesture.view?.transform = (localrotateGesture.view?.transform)!.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
}
    localrotateGesture.rotation = 0

}
```

Works fine. I then access subviews and try to invert the movement

```
    var thisCell = localrotateGesture.view as! CustomMessageCell
    thisCell.cellButtonsStackView.transform = (localrotateGesture.view?.transform.inverted())!.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

The subviews rotate the first attempt, and after that it doesn't! What is going on?